# Filtering an api response in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filter

I am pretty new to react. I am using react-redux to call API's with Axios. I have successfully fetched the result using `.get`. Now I want to make a drop-down filter, in which if one selected should show the result of that particular type. For more convenience, I made a backend where the response is also sending an object i.e. `type`, which can be Internal or External. For more clarity, the response looks like this.

```
[
    {
        "id": 0,
        "title": "TestProductForAzure",
        "description": null,
        "owner": "Seeded Company",
        "link": null,
        "url": "http://localhost:54729/api/product/3",
        "type": "Internal",
        "rank": 0,
        "productid": 3
    },
    {
        "id": 0,
        "title": "Official example",
        "description": null,
        "owner": null,
        "link": "/search/product?url=https://support.example.com/en-ae",
        "url": "https://support.example.com/en-ae",
        "type": "External",
        "rank": 0,
        "productid": 0
    },
    {
        "id": 0,
        "title": "Example1 Support",
        "description": null,
        "owner": null,
        "link": "/search/product?url=https://support.example.com/",
        "url": "https://support.example.com/",
        "type": "External",
        "rank": 0,
        "productid": 0
    }
]
```

With result above you can see I am getting 2 types of results i.e. Internal and External.
On the frontend I want to make a dropdown which has options

```
Internal
External
```

and based on the selection I want to show the results what user selected, forexample if the user selects `Internal` only the internal result should be shown. Otherwise by default all the response should be shown like right now.

My .jsx file look like this. The comment `Filtering` will tell you what I have tried till now, but I am clueless on this. How can I put the dropdown which lets the component to load again and show the selected results. Moreover, in the `return` I am already filtering out `result.type` putting `Internal` ones blue and `External` ones red.

```
function onClickHandler(id) {
  console.log("calling Details Product", id);
  detailsProduct(id);
}

export default function SingleSearchResult(props) {


  let result = props.result;
  console.log("Props Single Search", props);
  const bgColor = useState("black");


  //Collapse For External
  const [collapse, setCollapse] = useState(false);

  const toggle = () => setCollapse(!collapse);

  const loading = () => <Spinner color="success" />;

  const onClickHandlerTup = () => {
    cogoToastHelper.success("You liked this Product");
  };

  const onClickHandlerDown = () => {
    cogoToastHelper.warn("You disliked this Product");
  };

  //Filtering
    let Internal_type = this.props.result.filter(function(types) {
    return types.type === "Internal";
  });

  let External_type = this.props.result.filter(function(types) {
    return types.type === "External";
  });



  return (
    <div className="row">
      <div className="s130">
        <div className="col-lg">
          <div className="container">
            <div className=""></div>
            {/* Loader Here ibox-content*/}
            {result.type === "Internal" ? (
              <Link
                value={result.productid}
                to={DoctorProductLocation.path}
                onClick={() => onClickHandler(result.productid)}
                //onClickHandler(result.productid)
              >
                <h3 style={{ color: "#1a0dab" }}>
                  {result.title}
                  <hr></hr>
                </h3>
              </Link>
            ) : (
              //Try With OnClick Function
              <a onClick={toggle} target="_blank">
                <h3 style={{ color: "RED" }}>
                  {result.title}
                  <hr></hr>
                </h3>
              </a>
            )}
            <p className="p1">{result.description}</p>
          </div>

          {result.type === "Internal" ? (
            <Link
              className="iUh30"
              to={DoctorProductLocation.path}
              onClick={() => onClickHandler(result.productid)}
            >
            </Link>
          ) : (
            <Collapse isOpen={collapse}>
              <Card style={{ maxWidth: "100%" }}>
                <CardBody>
                  Source:
                  <a className="iUh30" href={result.url} target="_blank">
                    <a>{result.url}</a>
                  </a>
                </CardBody>
              </Card>
              <Card style={{ maxWidth: "100%" }}>
                <CardBody>
                  <a
                    href={result.url + "subscribe"}
                    style={{ color: "#1a0dab" }}
                    target="_blank"
                  >
                    Subscribe
                  </a>
                  <p>{result.description} </p>
                  <GoThumbsup
                    className="col-4"
                    onClick={onClickHandlerTup}
                  ></GoThumbsup>
                  <GoThumbsdown
                    className="col-4"
                    onClick={onClickHandlerDown}
                  ></GoThumbsdown>
                </CardBody>
              </Card>

              <br></br>
            </Collapse>
          )}

          {/* RANKING */}
          {/* <p className="rank">Visited {result.rank} times</p> */}
        </div>
      </div>
      <Footer></Footer>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: `props.result` is an array right? so it's not possible to check `result.type === "Internal"`. I guess that you want to render a component for each item in the array and based on its `type` right?

Comment: @MoshFeu ```props.result``` is the json result which I am getting from api. It contains object  ```type``` which I am refering with ```result.type === "Internal"``` . And yes I want to render / load the component based on the selected ```type```

Comment: Right. So there is no `result.type`. Do you know how to render a component for each item in an array?

Comment: @MoshFeu I'm pretty new on this ! All I know that we can user ```forEach``` for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to render a component for each item in an array, you should use `.map()` that except the array and returns a JSX element. Like this:

```js
data.map(item => (
    <div>
      {item.title}
    </div>
))
```

Inside that, you can use ternary to render one component if `true` and another if not, Like this:

```js
data.map(item => (
    item.type === 'Internal' ?
    <div className="internal">
      {item.title}
    </div> :
    <div className="external">
      {item.title}
    </div>
))
```

If you want to filter based on a dropdown's value, you can filter like any array in javascript - `.filter()` and convert the result using `.map()`, like this:

```
.filter(item => !this.state.filter || item.type === this.state.filter)
```

This is, obviously, a simpler example than your code, but it should works the same.

Working demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-yldai7?file=index.js

Comment: That's great. Thanks for this. But the main thing for me where I was confused, is the use of drop down, when selected I want to take that value and match whether ```Internal``` is selected or ```External```, based on that I want to do this work that you sent. But How can I use the dropdown and take the value and then match?

Comment: During your comment, I've updated my answer :) Check it out..

Comment: Glad to hear :) Good luck!